# Dropping images form a web browser to a Delphi Control

Tags: image, delphi, drag-and-drop

I am building an application that reads Metadata contained in images generated by AI systems (like Stable Diffusion) to save what is called the prompt: the generation parameters of the image.

Using a single form with a TPanel and a TImage, I am able to drag and drop an image from the windows explorer (and some image viewers as well) to my Delphi form and have it displayed. File name, extension, path... everything is available through the buffer variable. And the Metadata is accessed through [Phil Harvey's Exif tool](https://exiftool.org/) directly in my Delphi application as well.

The dragging and dropping of "local" files was done like this :

In the private section are declared :

```
private
    { Private declarations }
    originalPanel1WindowProc : TWndMethod;
    procedure Panel1WindowProc (var Msg : TMessage) ;
    procedure Panel1ImageDrop (var Msg : TWMDROPFILES) ;
  public
```

And the rest of the code is just three procedures:

```
procedure TfrmAnyImage.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  originalPanel1WindowProc := Panel1.WindowProc;
  Panel1.WindowProc := Panel1WindowProc;
  DragAcceptFiles(Panel1.Handle,true);
end;

procedure TfrmAnyImage.Panel1WindowProc(var Msg: TMessage) ;
begin
  if Msg.Msg = WM_DROPFILES then
      Panel1ImageDrop(TWMDROPFILES(Msg))
    else
      originalPanel1WindowProc(Msg) ;
end;

procedure TfrmAnyImage.Panel1ImageDrop(var Msg: TWMDROPFILES);
var
  buffer : array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  DragQueryFile(Msg.Drop, 0, @buffer, sizeof(buffer)) ;
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(buffer);
end;
```

"Quick and dirty" as one would say, but it works.

After searching for a long time, I came across 2 extensions that I tried :

- [The Drag and Drop Component Suite for Delphi](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop) by Melander that spared me the manual writing of the above
- [Drop Target Files & Picture](https://www.3delite.hu/Object%20Pascal%20Developer%20Resources/DropTargetFilesAndPicture.html) by 3delite that solved the problem of accepting images from a chrome based browser

My problems are as follows:

- the first one works great for all "local" files drag and drop operations (by local I mean windows explorer based), but I can't get it to accept an image dropped directly from my day to day browser (Opera)
- the second one is absolutely great at accepting images dragged from any chrome based browser, but I can't get it to accept "local" files.
- as I have them target the same component, they block each other and only one type of drag and drop can be set on the form

**I did declare two different drop components on the same form to have the best of the two worlds, directing the user to drop on A or B according to the source of the drop, and it works**. But it's not satisfying...

I have thoroughly read through [How to receive data dragged from other applications](https://delphidabbler.com/articles/article-24) many times, but I'm afraid this is above my level of knowledge and understanding. This is why I turn to you.

Is there a way, fully programmaticaly or not, to have one TImage on one TPanel accept any image, be it from a windows explorer source or a chormium based browser source (not a TWebBrowser component, a day to day browser)?

Or if it is not possible, is there a way to "detect" what source the drag is coming from and activate one procedure or the other accordingly?

Thanks in advance and thank you for reading me so far.

Comment: You should probably implement true OLE drag and drop (IDropTarget etc.).

Comment: "I have thoroughly read through How to receive data dragged from other applications many times, but I'm afraid this is above my level of knowledge and understanding. This is why I turn to you." Well, that is what you need, so if it is above your level of knowledge and understanding, I'm afraid you have a problem. You could consider hiring someone to do it for you.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*You should probably implement true OLE drag and drop (IDropTarget etc.)*" - that is exactly what both solutions the OP tried do implement. The OP is likely just not using them correctly/fully to accomplish all of the tasks being asked for.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand
Thank your for your answers. Indeed I have a problem but I'm not dropping the project (it's a personal thing) and continue reading and testing. Is it allowed to post an answer to show my progress (and have it evnetually reviewed) once I've worked some more on the subject, or is it better to post as comments only?

Comment: @Mathmathou: Stack Overflow has a rather strict policy on being about questions and answers -- it's not intended to be a forum. So an answer should probably be an answer in the proper sense, and comments are strictly speaking only allowed to suggest clarifications of Qs and As. You may want to see https://stackoverflow.com/tour.